# How can I resolve my Trigger.io Certificate error?

Tags: trigger.io

How can I resolve my Trigger.io Certificate error? I need to know how to get my first sample app packaged.

> [INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.17
>   [INFO] Update result: you already have the latest tools
>   [INFO] Checking JavaScript files...
>   [INFO] JavaScript check complete
>   [INFO] Verifying your configuration settings...
>   [INFO] Configuration settings check complete
>   [INFO] Development build created. Use forge run to run your app.
>   [INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.17
>   [INFO] Checking JavaScript files...
>   [INFO] JavaScript check complete
>   [INFO] Verifying your configuration settings...
>   [INFO] Configuration settings check complete
>   [INFO] Starting package process for iOS
>   [INFO] Going to package: /Users/tyler/forge-workspace/Messagee-native-app-using-Apigee/development/ios/device-ios.app
>   [INFO] Plist OK
>   [INFO] No Provisioned Devices, profile is Appstore
>   [ERROR] Failed when running /usr/bin/codesign: ios_development: no identity found

Answer (score 3):

From the traceback, it seems  you're using a distribution (Appstore only) provisioning profile - is that really what you mean? The built app will not be runnable on any devices...

But that's a tangent - the issue here is that you've configured the command to use the "ios_development" development certificate, which you don't have on your machine.

If you follow [these instructions](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/best_practice/release_mobile.html#ios), we walk you through how to create the right certificates, profiles and so on.

If you could update your question with information about what certificate(s) you have on your machine (look in Keychain Access), what provisioning profiles you have available (look in Xcode Organizer), I'll be able to get more specific with the command to run.

Also, enabling debug output with `--verbose` on the command line or the "Show debug output" checkbox in the Toolkit really helps step through these things.